# Use several checkboxes to change the results of a SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview on a page that displays the results of a GridQuery. This works OK. 
I have a checkbox controls on the same page that if checked, should add to the where clause of the GridQuery. How do I check the state of the checkboxes so it will run the query with or without filtering.

aspx:

```
<table class="filter_component_css">
          <tr>
             <td>miap</td>
             <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="miap_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>purchase order</td>
             <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="po_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>manufacturer</td>
              <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="manufacturer_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>spare parts</td>
              <td><asp:CheckBox CssClass="search_format" ID="parts_checkbox" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="spareParts_Checked"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>first fills</td>
              <td><asp:CheckBox CssClass="search_format" ID="fills_checkbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="firstFills_Checked"/></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>special tools</td>              
              <td><asp:Checkbox CssClass="search_format" ID="tools_checkbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="specialTools_Checked"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>tag</td>
              <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="tag_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
          </tr>  
          <tr>
              <td>item to be lubricated</td>
              <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="item_lubricated_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>include deleted</td>
              <td><asp:CheckBox CssClass="search_format" ID="include_deleted_checkbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="includeDeleted_Checked"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>include purchase orders manually inserted</td>
              <td><asp:CheckBox CssClass="search_format" ID="manually_inserted_checkbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="manualInsert_Checked"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>material code</td>
              <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="material_code_textbox" runat="server"/></td>
          </tr>   
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="buttonReset"  CssClass="filter_component_css_3" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="submitResetClick"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="buttonSearch"  CssClass="filter_component_css_3" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="submitSearchClick"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Search" runat="server" ConnectionString="Server=kzatdev04;Database=AgipKco.CMHS;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
           selectCommand="select aktb_ItemUpload.miap as miap, 
                aktb_PurchaseOrder.pocode as pocode, 
                aktb_PurchaseOrder.materialdescription as materialdescription,
                aktb_Supplier.name as suppliername,
                aktb_Manufacturer.name as manufacturername,
                aktb_CMRFHeader.spareparts as spareparts,
                aktb_CMRFHeader.consumables as firstfills,
                aktb_CMRFHeader.specialtools as specialtools,
                aktb_PrjStrTag.tag as tag,
                aktb_ItemTobeLubricated.itemtobelubricated as itemtobelubricated,
                aktb_ProjectStructure.subsystem as subsystem,
                aktb_ProjectStructure.cu as cu,
                aktb_ProjectStructure.ffu as ffu,
                aktb_ProjectStructure.deleted as ps_deleted,
                aktb_PurchaseOrder.manuallyInserted as po_manuallyinserted,
                aktb_ItemUpload.materialCode as materialcode
                from aktb_ItemUpload>

                <FilterParameters> 
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="parts_checkbox" Name="parts_checkbox" PropertyName="Checked" /> 
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="fills_checkbox" Name="fills_checkbox" PropertyName="Checked" /> 
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tools_checkbox" Name="tools_checkbox" PropertyName="Checked" /> 
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="include_deleted_checkbox" Name="parts_checkbox" PropertyName="Checked" /> 
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="manually_inserted_checkbox" Name="manually_inserted_checkbox" PropertyName="Checked" /> 
                </FilterParameters> 

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

c#:

```
protected void submitSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
                ViewState.Add("flag", true);

                    GridViewS.DataSource = SqlDataSource_Search;

                    SqlDataSource_Search.FilterExpression = "miap like '%" + miap_textbox.Text + "%' and pocode like '%" + po_textbox.Text + "%' and materialdescription like '%" + material_desc_textbox.Text + "%' and suppliername like '%" + supplier_textbox.Text + "%' and manufacturername like '%" + manufacturer_textbox.Text
                     + "%' and tag like '%" + tag_textbox.Text + "%' and itemtobelubricated like '%" + item_lubricated_textbox.Text + "%' and subsystem like '%" + subsystem_textbox.Text
                     + "%' and cu like '%" + cu_textbox.Text + "%' and ffu like '%" + ffu_textbox.Text + "%' and materialcode like '%" + material_code_textbox.Text + "%'";

                    GridViewS.DataBind();        
    }
```

Comment: Question, how to implement logic - 5 checkboxes in form, if checked some of them - Results of SqlDataSource are changed

Comment: added code - what i have tried

Comment: I strongly believe in structuring applications in several layers. Especially, in your case, I would create a business object, with a method that accepts all your filters, and handle the filter within this method.